# System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' ┃Visual Studio/VB.NET 2022 IDE Version

Tags: vb.net

**Error**: An exception is thrown in the procedure EnterHours()

**Description of method EnterHours()**:
The file *HoursWeek1.txt* stores the number of hours each employee has worked in week 1,
in the order:

- employee number
- number of hours worked.

For example, the first set of data is for employee *21548* who has worked *50.0* hours.

The method *EnterHours()*:

- reads in the values from the file
- finds the location of each employee in EmployeeArray
- calls the method *SetPay()* for each employee.

**HoursWeek1.txt** (sample data)

```
21548
50.0
12452
48.0
51947
51
82610
47.5
02586
28.5
65912
38.0
42004
22.5
51847
10.0
```

**The desired output is:**

```
21548 889.99994
12452 730.56
51947 1216.1409
82610 502.07498
02586 674.91565
65912 475
42004 768.5955
```

**My output is** :

```
Invalid file
Invalid file
12452
0
Invalid file
Web Developer
0
Invalid file
Interface Manager
0
Invalid file
```

**EnterHours method**:

```
 Sub EnterHours()

     Dim EmployeeNumber As String
     Dim NumWorkH As Double
     Dim FileReader As StreamReader
     Try
         FileReader = File.OpenText("HoursWeek1.txt")

         While FileReader.Peek <> -1
             EmployeeNumber = FileReader.ReadLine()
             NumWorkH = FileReader.ReadLine()

             For i = 0 To 7
                 If EmployeeArray(i).GetEmployeeNumber() = EmployeeNumber Then
                     EmployeeArray(i).SetPay(1, NumWorkH)
                 End If
             Next
         End While
         FileReader.Close()
     Catch Ex As Exception
         Console.WriteLine("Invalid file")
     End Try
 End Sub
```

**Complete code**:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Class Employee
    Private HourlyPay As Double
    Private EmployeeNumber As String
    Private JobTitle As String
    Private PayYear2022(51) As Double

    Sub New(NewHourlyPay, NewEmployeeNumber, NewJobTitle)
        HourlyPay = NewHourlyPay
        EmployeeNumber = NewEmployeeNumber
        JobTitle = NewJobTitle

        For i = 0 To 1
            PayYear2022(i) = 0.0
        Next
    End Sub

    Function GetEmployeeNumber()
        Return EmployeeNumber
    End Function

    Overridable Sub SetPay(WeekNumber, NumHours)
        PayYear2022(WeekNumber - 1) = NumHours * HourlyPay
    End Sub

    Function GetTotalPay()
        Dim Sum As Double
        For i = 0 To 51
            Sum = Sum + PayYear2022(i)
        Next
        Return Sum
    End Function
End Class

Class Manager
    Inherits Employee
    Private BonusValue As Double

    Sub New(NewBonusVal, NewHourlyPay, NewEmployeeNumber, NewJobTitle)
        MyBase.New(NewHourlyPay, NewEmployeeNumber, NewJobTitle)
        BonusValue = NewBonusVal
    End Sub

    Overrides Sub SetPay(WeekNumber, NumHours)
        MyBase.SetPay(WeekNumber, NumHours * (BonusValue / 100) + 1)

    End Sub
End Class
```

**Program**:

```
Module Program
    Dim EmployeeArray(7) As Employee

    Sub Main()
        Dim NumEmployee As Integer = 0
        Dim FileReader As StreamReader

        Try
            FileReader = File.OpenText("Employees.txt")
            While FileReader.Peek() <> -1
                Dim HourlyPay As Double = Double.Parse(FileReader.ReadLine())
                Dim EmployeeNumber As String = FileReader.ReadLine()
                Dim BonusValueString As String = FileReader.ReadLine()
                Dim Bonus As Double
                Dim JobTitle As String = FileReader.ReadLine()

                If Double.TryParse(BonusValueString, Bonus) Then
                    EmployeeArray(NumEmployee) = New Manager(Bonus, HourlyPay, EmployeeNumber, JobTitle)
                Else
                    EmployeeArray(NumEmployee) = New Employee(HourlyPay, EmployeeNumber, JobTitle)
                End If

                NumEmployee = NumEmployee + 1
                If NumEmployee >= EmployeeArray.Length Then Exit While ' Exit the loop if the array is full
            End While

            FileReader.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid file")
        End Try

        For i = 0 To 7
            Call EnterHours()
            Console.WriteLine(EmployeeArray(i).GetEmployeeNumber())
            Console.WriteLine(EmployeeArray(i).GetTotalPay())
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub EnterHours()

        Dim EmployeeNumber As String
        Dim NumWorkH As Double
        Dim FileReader As StreamReader
        Try
            FileReader = File.OpenText("HoursWeek1.txt")

            While FileReader.Peek <> -1
                EmployeeNumber = FileReader.ReadLine()
                NumWorkH = FileReader.ReadLine()

                For i = 0 To 7
                    If EmployeeArray(i).GetEmployeeNumber() = EmployeeNumber Then
                        EmployeeArray(i).SetPay(1, NumWorkH)
                    End If
                Next
            End While

            FileReader.Close()
        Catch Ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid file")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: This is not an IDE issue. This is as code issue. Tag removed.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) - it's for C#, but the same principles apply to VB.NET.

Comment: The following may be of interest as well: [System.IO.File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-8.0), [Using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) and [Collections (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/collections)